# Android: How to change HomeAsUpIndicator color programmatically

Tags: android, colors, searchview

This is the flow of my app.
In this page, I have a navigation drawer and a magnifying glass button to bring up the search view.
[Screen shot No.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bCbi.png)

Clicking on the magnifying glass shows this page:
[Screen shot No.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkua5.png)

As you can see, the back arrow in the second screen shot is in white which is not very visible. I tried to change the color by doing this under

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(...)
```

The code:

```
int upId = getResources().getIdentifier("up", "id", "android");
if (upId > 0) {
  ImageView up = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(upId);
  up.getDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
}
```

It changed the color of the hamburger of the first screen shot from orange to black; therefore, it did change the indicator color but in the wrong place. Is it possible to change the color of the back arrow in the second screen shot? The page is written in Fragment.

Comment: Not really sure about your question.What is your default icon color?

Comment: It seems like you are using old Action Bar. You need to upgrade your application to use Toolbar and then look for how to change color in new AppCompat theme.

Comment: @OsamaAftab, I would like to change the color of the HomeAsUpIndicator arrow shown in the second screen shot programmatically. I didn't set any color and it is white.